# Creating random Tensors in Swift for Tensorflow

Tags: swift, numpy, tensorflow, random, tensor

I'm trying to use Swift for Tensorflow API, and I'm not able to find a way to create Tensors with random normal initialization.

Currently I'm getting an array from numpy to construct a Tensor struct:

```
let np = Python.import("numpy")

let w_np = np.random.randn(10, 10).astype(np.float32)
let w = Tensor<Float32>(numpy: w_np)!
```

Is there Swift for Tensorflow pure way to get random arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, `Tensor` has an `init` function for constructing a tensor of a certain shape and random values. For instance:

```
let input = Tensor<Float>(randomUniform: [64, 28, 28, 32])
```